# Rename legend label in prometheus by script?

Tags: docker, prometheus

I have a simple query in Prometheus like:

`irate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{job="job-name",device=~"br-.*",name="a-name"}[5m])`

The Legend contains: `{{device}} received`

On the Panel i see my metric graphics and to the right a legend list with all network "devices" by it's name like:

```
br-a539a330b41b received
br-6c596943b7c8 received
br-dc406d831d4e received
[...]
```

If I ask docker network on that computer I can get a name list like:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-278-0-45:~$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                 DRIVER    SCOPE
0a9c74974c7f   bridge               bridge    local
6c596943b7c8   a-service_default    bridge    local
dc406d831d4e   b-service_default    bridge    local
a539a330b41b   c-service_default    bridge    local
68a058a0a38b   host                 host      local
0b101d111154   none                 null      local
[...]
```

Within a simple bash snipped as follows I could translate the current given Panel Legends to it's better understandable service names.

`docker network ls | grep 6c596943b7c8 | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/_default//'`

Is there a simple way to translate the current Legend {{device}} to something more readable like the names found in docker network ls?

So I get a legend like:

```
a-service received
b-service received
c-service received
[...]
```

Or is there an other ''simple'' way, to translate such uuid like bridge network names?

One ''other'' way could be to "manipulate" the node_exporter output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [label_map](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_map) function with the `network_id -> network_name` mapping. For example:

```
label_map(
  irate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{job="job-name",device=~"br-.*",name="a-name"}[5m]),
  "device",
  "br-6c596943b7c8", "a-service",
  "br-dc406d831d4e", "b-service",
  "br-a539a330b41b", "c-service",
)
```

The `label_map` function is available in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). I hope it will be added to Prometheus soon.

Comment: This is nice, but will not work for me, because the br-* names will change after a new deployment. Isn't there a more automatically way?

Comment: The `node_exporter` doesn't export interface name in labels for `node_network_receive_bytes_total` metric. It would be better filing a feature request at https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues for adding the ability to put network interface name into labels for this metric.